# Adding line after section heading

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, rules, sectsty

I am trying to add a horizontal line (like `\hrule`) that starts just after each section's heading, fills the rest of the line, and is vertically aligned with the heading, as shown below.
[image: Desired output]

To do so, I have defined a `\newcommand` called `\raisedrule` that generates the desired horizontal line (following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553392/latex-rule-filling-the-line)). However, I am having difficulty incorporating it into the definition of the sections' headings.

I have tried using the `titlesec` package, but I have not found a way to generate a line that is shorter than the text's width. I have also tried using the `sectsty` package, using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\raisedrule}[2][0em]{\leaders\hbox{\rule[#1]{1pt}{#2}}\hfill}

\usepackage{sectsty} 
    \sectionfont{
        \setmainfont{Arial} \raisedrule[0.32em]{0.75pt}
    }

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\section*{SECTION HEADING}

\end{document}
```

which, not only gives a "Leaders not followed by proper glue." error, but I don't think would generated the required output anyway.

Note that, as shown in the code, I also want to change the font of the heading, which may be important for the solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: \hrulefill will come in handy here

Comment: @SeanAllred I cannot see images on Imgur right now, could you please describe to me the vertical position of the desired rule? I'm not sure if is as in my answer or if a simple `\hrulefill` is enough.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It's a hair under 1ex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to switch to [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) which offers more customization capabilities (I also used [`xhfill`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xhfill) to easily produce the rule, but this is optional):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{xhfill}

\newcommand\ruleafter[1]{#1~\xrfill[.7ex]{1pt}}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\fontspec{Arial}}{\thesection}{1em}{\ruleafter}

\begin{document}

\section*{SECTION HEADING}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Adjust the rule settings according to your needs; you might want to adjust the space between the title and the rule and, as **Sean Allred** mentions in [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268397/adding-line-after-section-heading/268402#comment644131_268402), it's enough to use `\fontspec` instead of `\setmainfont`.

Comment: Nice tip about `\xrfill` :) I was having trouble with a `\raisebox{0.8ex}{\hrulefill}` solution. I'd stick a `\quad` in there for aesthetic, though. And I wouldn't use `\setmainfont` there; a simple `\fontspec` would suffice.

Comment: @SeanAllred Yes. I added some remark about adding some space and changed to `\fontspec`.